# Some Deezer Song IDs can not be fetched from EchoNest

Tags: deezer, echonest

I am trying to get some EchoNest parameters like valence and arousal for songs using the Deezer ID for the query. For the most songs it works fine, but sometimes it seems like there is no connection between the Deezer ID and the EchoNest ID.

For example this famous song:
Katy Perry - Roar
www.deezer.com/track/69863371

Query:
http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/track/profile?api_key=EGJMZDJPOFDOWHUJV&id=deezer:track:69863371&bucket=audio_summary

Answer:
{"response": {"status": {"version": "4.2", "code": 5, "message": "The Identifier specified does not exist"}}}

If I try it by ARTIST and TITLE it's working:
http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/search?api_key=EGJMZDJPOFDOWHUJV&format=json&results=1&artist=katy%20perry&title=roar&bucket=audio_summary

Is this the only way in this case?

Thanks
Patrick